# Get encoder from trained UNet

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, autoencoder, encoder-decoder

I have trained a UNet model on some images but now, I want to extract the encoder part of the model. My UNet has the following architecture:

```
UNet(
  (conv_final): Conv2d(8, 1, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
  (down_convs): ModuleList(
    (0): DownConv(
      (conv1): Conv2d(1, 8, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (conv2): Conv2d(8, 8, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (pool): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    )
    (1): DownConv(
      (conv1): Conv2d(8, 16, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (conv2): Conv2d(16, 16, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (pool): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    )
    (2): DownConv(
      (conv1): Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (conv2): Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (pool): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    )
    (3): DownConv(
      (conv1): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (pool): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    )
    (4): DownConv(
      (conv1): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    )
  )
  (up_convs): ModuleList(
    (0): UpConv(
      (upconv): ConvTranspose2d(128, 64, kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2))
      (conv1): Conv2d(128, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    )
    (1): UpConv(
      (upconv): ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2))
      (conv1): Conv2d(64, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (conv2): Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    )
    (2): UpConv(
      (upconv): ConvTranspose2d(32, 16, kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2))
      (conv1): Conv2d(32, 16, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (conv2): Conv2d(16, 16, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    )
    (3): UpConv(
      (upconv): ConvTranspose2d(16, 8, kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2))
      (conv1): Conv2d(16, 8, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (conv2): Conv2d(8, 8, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    )
  )
)
```

I have tried to load the encoder layers through model.down_convs but I get the following error:

> TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) in
> ----> 1 res = encoder(train_img)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/work/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py
> in call(self, *input, **kwargs) 548 result =
> self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs) 549 else: –> 550 result =
> self.forward(*input, **kwargs) 551 for hook in
> self._forward_hooks.values(): 552 hook_result = hook(self, input,
> result)
>
> TypeError: forward() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I have attached the [model](https://gist.github.com/Flock1/34b5eb8685df07bad950868f57577693) so you can try it out. And the weights from [here](https://github.com/Flock1/solar)

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
net = UNet(8) # network object having 8 classes
net.load_state_dict(torch.load('PATH'))
print(net) #see the names of the layers of encoder. 
net1 = net.down_convs #as you have named the encoder as down_convs

#net1 is your encoder.
```

Comment: I've tried that. Here's the original post: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/get-encoder-from-trained-unet/95053

I get the same error